# Dynamic url as data-attribute of pseudo-element in css and D3JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have to change dynamically the icon url of a list of links in the css pseudo-element. I think the best way is to pass the link of the selected icon by an attribute, but I can't get it working as a url.

**CSS**

```
a[data-icon]:before{
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
content:url(attr(data-icon)); 
}
```

**D3JS** (where I retreive the iconURL)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < JSONclassesInfo.typesList.length; i++){
      if (JSONclassesInfo.typesList[i].name == type){

       temp = JSONclassesInfo.typesList[i].compatible;
       iconRoute= JSONclassesInfo.typesList[i].icon;
      }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                d3.select('.dropdown')
                    .append("li")
                    .attr('class','listOpt')
                    .append('a')
                    .text(temp[i])
                    .attr("href","#")
                    .attr('data-icon',iconRoute);


              }
```

Comment: Not possible using this method. You can't use an atttibute as a URL.

Comment: It seems you want to turn the icon into a link. Why don't you do that in the for loop where you retrieve the iconRoute? You are already doing some DOM manipulation there. Setting the content in CSS is unreliable.

Comment: I don't know how to set it in the for loop. Any options I have tried have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget to use `attr()` CSS function in content to URLs. Just change this:

```
 .attr('data-icon',iconRoute);
```

With this:

```
 .css('background-image',iconRoute);
```

Comment: Maybe this is the way of the solution, but when I change this it says me .css is not a function.

Comment: Finally I have found the solution, could you edit it? Because the .css function doesn't work.
`.style('background-image','url('+icon+')')`

Comment: Is this answer your solution? Can you share? Can you upvote please? :)

Comment: I don't know why d3.js haven't got `css()` jquery method, but it's exactly the same as your `style()`method, because it changes the `style` html attribute

Comment: Yes, it seems like d3js doesn't have this css() method. Nice solution, thank you